# Detect only person class

Tags: python, opencv, darknet

I am trying to detect only 'person' class in a video using yolo v3.

To do so, i made the following modifications:

```
I changed number of filters (lines 603, 689, 776 ) from 255 to 18 in yolov3.cfg.
I changed the number of classes from 80 to 1 in the yolov3.cfg and the coco.data files.
I edited the coco.names file in order to leave only the "person" class.
```

The model runs but does not detect anything in the video feed.

Could you please advise on what might be going wrong and kindly provide suggestions?

Thanks,
Pavlos

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change config file then you must change weights file - train your custom network: [instructions](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet#how-to-train-to-detect-your-custom-objects). In your case darknet can't correct parse the weights file and don't works.

Or you can use default weight and cfg, detects all objects but in darknet sources (in C code) pass only persons.